# Send Media Stream to Clients from Server

Tags: javascript, buffer, electron, webrtc, mediastream

I need to send a MediaStream from a electron desktop Capture to a Live HTML5 Video tag using express. The problem is that a I can't create a fs.createReadStream from a Media Stream. I do not think I need to use WEB-RTC for this. Code is below

app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const {desktopCapturer} = require('electron');
function getDesktop(callback) {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, 
function(error, sources) {
        if (error) return callback(error)
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: false,
            video: {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                    chromeMediaSourceId: sources[0].id,
                    minWidth: 1280,
                    maxWidth: 1280,
                    minHeight: 720,
                    maxHeight: 720
                }
            }
        }).then(function(stream) {
            return callback(null,stream)
            video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => video.play()
        }).catch(function(e) {
            return callback(e);
        })
    })
}
getDesktop(function(err,stream) {
    app.get('/',function(req,res) {
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/client.html'))
    });
    app.get('/video',function(req,res) {

            ///Send LIVE data to HTML5 Video Tag


    });
    app.listen(80,function() {
        console.log('Streaming')
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be "live" you need to implement WebRTC on your server.

If a delay is acceptable, the MediaStreamRecorder API shown in https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/ might solve the problem. You can send chunks of data in the ondataavailable handler.